# function to define current class in js

Tags: javascript, class

What I want to do is to have a function that executes to define a "current" class to an `<li>` tag, depending on the page name. For example, if the page is named index.php, I want the function to determine if the link within the `<li>` tag is the same name as the page (index.php). I'm sorry I'm not the best at explaining this. Here's an example code.

```
<ul id="navigation"><li><a href="index.php"></li></ul>.
```

I want the class "current" defined into the `<li>` tag if the link is the same as the page name. Is there any way to do this? Or am I on a futile mission?

Answer (score 0):

Well...okay...

```
function liClass(context) {
   //Choose your parent node
   context = context || document;

   var pathparts = window.location.pathname.split('/'); //split on path
   var curfile = pathparts[pathparts.length-1]; //last item is the filename right?

   var lis = context.getElementsByTagName('li');
   for (var i=0, l=lis.length; i<l; i++) {
     var a = lis[i].getElementsByTagName('a');

     if (!a.length) continue; //li has no a, moving on...

     //Okay, this match might need some work, tried
     //to make it fairly forgiving, tweak for your needs
     if (a[0].href.indexOf(curfile) != -1) lis[i].className = 'current';
   }
}
```

Feel free to try it out, let me know if it works or not, cause I did not test it...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is you want to change the look of links that are pointing to the present page.  Here is what the code would look like.

```
var list=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var page=window.location.pathname;
var i=list.length;
while(i--){
  if(list[i].src.indexOf(page)>0){
    list[i].className='current';
  }
}
```

Note this is not a very accurate method.  The basic structure is correct, but for example a link somewebsite.com is actually pointing to somewebsite.com/index.php.  So depending on the link this could cause a problem on the home page.  Also, depending on how your links are setup you are probably going to have to the parse the page variable.  It will return something like. /help/faq/foo.php while the page may only have a link to faq/foo.php.  This all depends a lot on the setup of your site so I will leave it for you to tweak.

You added more details since I posted so I thought I would note that you would only need to make a list of the links in the `<li>` tags not all the `<a>` tags in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the href's of the location object, and the anchor DOM element. If they match, then that is the current class.

If the current page is `http://www.example.com/home` which contains a relative link,

```
<a href="/questions">Questions</a>
```

Then the href property of the DOM object will contain the absolute path, and not just the relative part.

```
link.href = "http://www.example.com/questions"
```

A function that loops through each link could then be written as,

```
function markCurrent(list) {
    var listItems = list.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var link = listItems[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if(link && (link.href == location.href)) {
            listItems[i].className += ' current';
        }
    }
}
```

Pass the root `<ul>` node to the function.

```
markCurrent(document.getElementById("navigation"));
```